# Arduino Twitter interaction

Tags: c, arduino

I'm writing some code for the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) with the [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) to interact with Twitter. I'm using the [Twitter library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TwitterLibrary), modified with the attachments to this post in order to use Wi-Fi: [Modified Twitter Library](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=121483.0).

I have it tweeting from the account, but now I'm wondering how I can check for things like tweets sent to my account or perhaps even if I have a new follower. Is there a way to do this on the Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've sorted that out, but in case you're still stuck:

You may want to have a look at:

- http://www.instructables.com/id/Twitter-controlled-Arduino-Outputs-no-PCLCD-Disp/step12/CODE-Now-add-info-to-Arduino-Sketch/

where it shows how to make an arduino check twitter and send tweets. You can go to previous pages in order to know how to get configuration data from twitter. Of course you may have to tweak the code for your needs...